# Dock overlays maximized windows after lock

Tags: dock

Whenever I lock my computer, after unlocking it, the dock overlays my windows. Minimizing and remaximizing the window fixes it, but it is very annoying (less so after I discovered the shortcut, but still). I have auto hide off, and I do not want to turn it on. Is there something I can do to fix this? I am running ubuntu 22.04.